# World texture doesn't show no matter what only in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, hdri, world

No matter if it's an environment texture or just a solid color it shows black.

I've even tried import worlds I made in other files

[image: With HDRI texture]

[image: and with just a solid color]

[image]

Comment: Is `"World.001"` assigned to the scene? *Properties > World Properties?*

Comment: yes it is. it even shows the texture on the little preview thing

Comment: Suggest share your blend: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: my file is 30.8mb

Comment: i uploaded it to here https://filebin.net/0rdibfsos6ys08u5

Comment: "This bin is empty." We are only interessted in the world settings so you can delete all irrelevant objects and textures to reduce the file size. However, don't forget to pack the HDRI.

Comment: yeah it's still uploading the site is slow only 50kbps.but ok Ill copy and it clear objects out

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=GK895a2L" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/GK895a2L/)

Comment: No issue here. Switch to the *Shading* workspace and enable *Scene World*, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmsRD.png

Comment: that's weird it actually worked once i unchecked lights

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your *Environment* is disabled in View Layer Properties > Filter:

[image]

Comment: Nice find! That's it...

Comment: thanks although brock did help i still only saw 1 color now this fixed it